# Plotting the paths taken by users in maps in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, ggmap

The following is my data,

```
Name    datetime             latitude    longitude  mode
A   2016-01-11 02:00:04 PST 40.07054    -76.288572  Cycle
A   2016-01-11 02:10:04 PST 39.82271579 -77.2300438 Cycle
A   2016-01-11 02:20:04 PST 39.83636098 -77.2061907 Cycle
B   2016-01-02 03:55:58 PST 40.009918   -75.188196  Car
B   2016-01-02 03:59:58 PST 39.94432271 -76.5933571 Car
B   2016-01-02 04:10:58 PST 39.91651225 -77.1641403 Car
```

I want to plot the path taken by each user along the date time. The output show be like distinct paths in a graph, where each path is for one user and in each latitude and longitude, the date and time is shown and also along the path, the mode should be shown. I am not sure how to do this in R. Can anybody help me in doing this?

The following is the reproducible example,

```
names = c('A','A','A','B','B','B')
datetime = c('2016-01-11 02:00:04 PST','2016-01-11 02:10:04 PST','2016-01-11 02:20:04 PST','2016-01-02 03:55:58 PST','2016-01-02 03:59:58 PST','2016-01-02 04:10:58 PST')
latitude = c(40.07054,39.82271579,39.83636098, 40.009918,39.94432271,39.91651225)
longitude = c(-76.288572, -77.2300438, -77.2061907,-75.188196, -76.5933571, -77.1641403)
mode = c('Bike','Bike','Bike','Car','Car','Car')
test = data.frame(names,datetime,latitude,longitude,mode)
```

Can anybody help me or suggest some way to plot this graphs?

Update:

The following is my try,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

map <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(test$longitude), lat = mean(test$latitude)), zoom = 4, maptype = "satellite", scale = 2)

basicmap <- ggmap(map)

basicmap + geom_path(data=test,aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, group=names, color=route),size=1)
```

But I am getting,

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(x = c(-76.288572, -77.2300438, -77.2061907, -75.188196,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 0
```

Thanks

Comment: @HubertL Please find the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names = c('A','A','A','B','B','B')
datetime = c('2016-01-11 02:00:04 PST','2016-01-11 02:10:04 PST','2016-01-11 02:20:04 PST','2016-01-02 03:55:58 PST','2016-01-02 03:59:58 PST','2016-01-02 04:10:58 PST')
latitude = c(40.07054,39.82271579,39.83636098, 40.009918,39.94432271,39.91651225)
longitude = c(-76.288572, -77.2300438, -77.2061907,-75.188196, -76.5933571, -77.1641403)
mode = c('Bike','Bike','Bike','Car','Car','Car')
test = data.frame(names,datetime,latitude,longitude,mode)

library("ggmap")
m <- get_map(location=c(lon=median(test$longitude), lat=median(test$latitude)), zoom=8)
ggmap(m) + geom_point(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, color=mode), data=test) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, color=mode), data=test)
```

This produces:
[image]

Do spend some time altering the colors, axes, and other things to make this more presentable, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This works. Can I also ask for a way which would display the time in which each location has been reached? I have the datetime variable and I would want that to display in each landmark

Comment: Maybe alter the `geom_point` size... longer time spent at that location is a bigger dot?

Comment: Can we display it as a text in each point? I am trying to do that. But Having difficulties in doing that.

Comment: `+ annotate("text", x=test$longitude, y=test$latitude, label=test$time)` for some "time" column in your dataframe. I haven't tested this...